# Why does this logcheck rule not work?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, logging

I have logcheck set up on a Ubuntu 9.10 machine. In /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/local-rules I have the line:

```
^\[\w{3} \w{3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4}\] \[error\] .*File does not exist: .*$
```

But I am still constantly being sent emails like this:

```
This email is sent by logcheck. If you no longer wish to receive
such mails, you can either deinstall the logcheck package or modify
its configuration file (/etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf).

System Events
=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[Mon Sep 12 07:19:57 2011] [error] [client 66.249.67.119] File does not exist: /var/sismo/build/cdc232/test/report/coverage/typhoon_assertion_parameterlist.php.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do more work than you have to? :)  It sounds like the data you want is `File does not exist`, which is a valid regular expression in itself.

You could expand this further--i.e., to include`[error]`--but in the end, do you really care about matching the rest of the line?  Hope this helps!

Comment: I was just trying to match the format of existing Apache rules which come pre-configured with logcheck. I've checked that the regex matches, see http://bit.ly/o7zZ7m - in any case, I'll try your suggestion.